# unreachable statement - break;

Tags: java

I'm trying to us an iterator to show a lot. I keep getting an error with the "break;" line. It says it is an unreachable statement. Any help is appreciated.

```
public Lot getLot(int number) {
    Lot foundLot = null;
    Iterator it = lots.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Lot b = (Lot) it.next();

        if (b.getNumber() == number) {
            foundLot = b;
            break;
            return foundLot;
        } else {
            System.out.println("lot " + number + " does not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to adhere to java formatting conventions, at least when posting code, it's easier to read

Comment: The unreachable code is actually on the line after the `break`!

Comment: You should consider to indent your code in a consistent manner. If you do, you should consider indent code in postings though ;)

Answer (score 8):

How do you expect to break from a loop, and then right after breaking from it, return something?

```
break;
return foundLot;
```

Answer (score 1):

It says that `return foundLot` is unreachable because of the `break` statement breaks out of the loop (bypassing the `return`).

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that the line after the break (`return foundLot;`) is an unreachable statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `return` is unreachable when the `break` is called.  This is an alternate version that does not use the break:

```
 public Lot getLot(int number) {  
    Lot foundLot = null;  
    Iterator it=lots.iterator();     
    while(it.hasNext() && foundLot == null) { 
      Lot b=(Lot) it.next();  
      if(b.getNumber() == number) {  
        foundLot = b;  
      }
    }
    if (foundLot == null) {
       System.out.println("lot "+number + " does not exist"); 
    }
    return foundLot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to as follows:

```
public Lot getLot(int number)  
{   
    Lot foundLot = null;   
    Iterator it=lots.iterator();      
    while(it.hasNext())  

        {    Lot b=(Lot) it.next();   

    if(b.getNumber() == number) {   
        foundLot = b;   
          break; 
    } 
 else { 
      System.out.println("lot "+number + " does not exist"); 
    } 
   }
 return foundLot;   
}
```